# Pronunciation of "й" in adjective endings

Tags: произношение

How exactly is й pronounced in adjective endings such as ий/ ый?

I seem to remember something, from some of the first grammar books that I read, about it being more or less silent--not having any sound. But recently I read that there should be a /j/ sound.

How does this work? What is the difference between ый and ы in normal speech? Do you hear the й? I 'm looking for a practical explanation not so much phonetic theory. Although the latter is welcome too.

E.G., красивый/ красивы

тихий/ тихи

I also read that in older styles speakers would pronounce the й much stronger. Or at least that's what I understood from the book I'm reading--see below.

**This is from Jones and Ward (1969), The phonetics of Russian. —**

[image: Old Pronunciation of -их]

[image: Modern]

---

**UPDATE-- So I read the introduction to the Book by Jones and Ward (1969) and they mention this--**

[image: **enter image description here**]

**Yet another Update-- I looked through some reference books and here's what they say about й—**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Both are valid I guess, at least according to this https://de.forvo.com/word/%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%B9/

Comment: user **maria_704** there articulates it accurately

Comment: @  Баян Купи-ка And the others say it incorrectly? Aren't they al Russians?

Comment: they say it either too softly to the point of being indistinguishable for an uninitiated listener or don't put enough effort in its articulation, after all they try to demonstrate the sound of a full word and not a specific phoneme

Comment: @ Баян Купи-ка Oh, I see. I could swear that in the first grammar books I ever read they gave advise like й is not pronounced, so don't worry bout it, but that being said I do hear the difference. Btw, on Wiki they point out that it can merge into a monothong. --..."at normal conversational speed, such unstressed endings may be monophthongized to [ɪ̟]."

Comment: i'm not in a position to argue with philologists and linguists, so let's just say it's my personal opinion that reduction of *-ий* isn't a prescriptive rule, where it would be incorrect to articulate it, this phenomenon happens naturally to the native speakers, but it's certainly not wrong and in my opinion desirable to make sure that **Й** is pronounced, and when it's monophongized the ending is still a wee bit longer than the simple **И/Ы**

Comment: Красивы/красивый - in the latter word _й_ is pronounced (never heard of reducing _й_). The question is good, and I wonder why no native speaker has mentioned than footnote 1 in 1969 book has nothing to do with the quality of _й_. It says of the quality of *и* in words like тих*и*й which was pronounced very similar to _тихой_ (_o_ sounds similar to 'schwa'). This pronounciation can sometimes today be heard in recorded classical Soviet theatre works (video, TV, audio), recorded Soviet songs (20s to 70s I'd say), and implied in poetry, and yes this is 'older mode' (now deemed old-fashioned).

Comment: @  alexsms --Thanks for explaining that point. Do you have any examples of the old mode of pronunciation?

Comment: @ alexsms Also--see the update to the question.

Comment: @ alexsms  Also, if you look closely, the х is not soft in the old mode.

Comment: indeed **Х** in **-хай/хый** isn't soft simply by the virtue of the vowel which doesn't allow for palatalisation

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка See the last update, if you are interested (in the post above).

Comment: if i get what the authors are saying, for **Й** in final position there're two possibilities, either devoicing into what i recognize as **-и/ыхь** (similar to the German ending syllable **-ig**) or reduction to **[i]** which would be just **и** (if i decypher their transcription symbols right), but not complete obliteration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not one of those cases where a sound can be reduced in spoken language without affecting the accuracy and euphony.

In fluent speech it can get swallowed so to speak at the end of words, due to its curtness, but it's a result of sloppiness and lack of effort, and ideally it has to be pronounced even if briefly.

If **Й** is left out, instead of **красивЫЙ** we get **красивЫ**, which are two different forms of the adjective, full singular and shortened plural  respectively. Likewise for **тихИЙ** vs **тихИ**.

Comment: How exactly does ый sound? I'm having trouble separating ы from ый (

Comment: @VCH250 check out [***THIS***](https://vocaroo.com/i/s1zwYvCENMYv) recording, in each pair 1st word is adjective in the shortened plural form (-Ы/И) while the 2nd is its full singular masculine form (-ЫЙ/ИЙ)... initially i thought to just refer you to Google Translate TTS voice but it turned out very bad at pronouncing this ending properly

Comment: I think I have it know, thanks :) It turns out I was more or less saying these endings correctly, but I didn't really. perceive й as a short и soft (although yes, that is it's name). Even in English I never thought of the y in "boy" as an e-like sound, but it truly is, if you isolate it. This has also helped me a lot with palatalized sounds--they always say to blend the consonants with /j/, and now I know what the hell that is, haha. I guess it was good I had this little crisis of confidence. it made me think harder about й and what it actually is, both in English and Russian. :)

Comment: @VCH250 don't know if you heard much of Public Enemy but Flava Flav, who's 1/2 of the duo, in his ad-libs would purposely distort the pronunciation of **boy** as **booyeee**, which brings out and emphasizes this short **E**, [**here at 0:13**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eysvw4XO-qI)

Comment: Yea, I know them, haha) I didn't realise how palatalised й was until today. What a cool discovery. I mean, I was not consciously aware of it.

Comment: @ Баян Купи-ка See the update to my question. It looks like the й is more or less not pronounced, at least according to linguists. Jones and Ward is the best reference work there is on the Russian Language. I hear the й in a lot of pronunciations. But I think this an analogous case to -ing in English. I would not have a problem with anyone dropping the "g". That's completely normal.

Comment: @VCH250 well this is what i more or less said as well in my response, but i consider this dropout to be a result of carelessness rather than a case of adherence to a certain pronunciation norm... as far as **-ing** is concerned, we've been taught that **G** isn't pronounced other than as a nasal sound and this is indeed how i think it's normally pronounced as far as i can hear, voicing **G** as hard **G** or as **K** would be incorrect, am i wrong?

Comment: I think the book is right. I have never thought of it earlier, but I caught myself not pronouncing j when the noun follows. If it is a separate adjective or it comes at the end of the sentence j is pronounced. That's my personal experience though.

Comment: @  Баян Купи-ка Sorry, I just meant that -ing ending can be "reduced" to "in"--talkin, walkin. There are various degrees of that, with the nasal "g" being just barely audible, or not at all. Saying such words with the nasal sound is correct, but I use both forms freely.

Answer (score 1):

Russian "й" sounds very much like English "y" in words: *"bo**y**", "ma**y**", "fe**y**".* Unlike in English sound "й" is never dropped or converted into "и", as it happens in words: *"icy", "chimney".*

As an example, my first name *"Витали**й**"* is typically pronounced by English speakers as *vee-tah-lee*, while the Russian pronunciation always preserves the semivowel at the end *vee-tah-lee**y***

Comment: So should I just add a quick "ye" sound to the end of adjectives? It's possible I do this correctly anyway, and I don't remember any grammar ever stressing this point, but it's also possible I've been staying it wrong for a long time.

Comment: @VCH250 Just make your "ye" sound at the end of full adjectives similar to pronunciation in [длинный](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9), [красивый](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9), [низкий](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)